# Error occurs when I try to create a new column with passwords in database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
import uuid


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///passwords.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Passwords(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    key = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
    return '<Name %r>' % self.id


@app.route("/passwords")
def passwords():
return render_template("passwords.html")


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/signup", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def new_user():
    if request.method == "POST":
        a = str(uuid.uuid4())
        print(a)
        key = Passwords(key=a)
        username = request.form["nm"]
        newuser = Passwords(name=username)
        try:
            db.session.add(newuser)
            db.session.commit()
            db.session.add(key)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for("new_user"))
        except:
            return "There was an error with your registration"
    else:
        passcodes = Passwords.query.order_by(Passwords.date_created)
        return render_template("signup.html", passcodes=passcodes)


@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    a = str(uuid.uuid4())
    print(a)
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["pw"]
        if user == a:
            return redirect(url_for("user", usr='Η Ακύρωση κράτησης ολοκληρώθηκε'))
        else:
            return render_template("login.html")
    else:

        return render_template("login.html")


@ app.route("/<usr>")
def user(usr):
    return "<h1>{}</h1>".format(usr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I get my website up and running but when I go to `/signup`, an error occurs:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: passwords.key
> [SQL: SELECT passwords.id AS passwords_id, passwords.name AS passwords_name, passwords."key" AS passwords_key, passwords.date_created AS passwords_date_created
> FROM passwords ORDER BY passwords.date_created]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy only handles creating and dropping tables; it has no support for adding, removing or amending columns, other than executing raw SQL `ALTER TABLE` statements.  If you need to perform such an action your options are, in ascending order of difficulty<sup>*</sup>:

- Drop the entire database (or delete the SQLite file) and run `db.create_all()` to recreate it

  - all data will be lost unless you back up the database
- Drop the affected table and run `db.create_all()` to recreate it

  - Use your database's console or some other database management application to drop the table
  - If the table is related to other tables via foreign keys then the related tables may need to be deleted too
  - All data in the table will be lost unless it's backed up
- Manually execute the necessary `ALTER TABLE` statement(s) in your database's console or some other database management application

  - You will need to ensure that the results match what SQLAlchemy would have created
- Use a migration utility to apply model changes to the database

  - [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is the obvious candidate, but there may be others

---

<sup>*</sup> All options assume you have updated the model class